# Fading in an image on top of a jPanel

Tags: java, image, swing, jpanel, fade

I want to have an image fade in onto a panel that is part of a card layout. When i'm at a certain place in the program, this panel will show on top and I then want the image to be loaded in with a fade-in effect.
This is a big project so I will only paste the relevant code.

I have a GUI class which contains the jFrame, all the jPanels etc. When a certain event is triggered, this code runs:

```
cardMain.show(pMain, "cLeprechaun");
FadeIn.run(pLeprechaun);
```

It loads up the correct panel and then runs a static method in the FadeIn class, that is supposed to add the image onto the panel pLeprechaun.

Here is the FadeIn class:

```
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class FadeIn extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    Image imagem;
    Timer timer;
    private float alpha = 0f;

    public FadeIn() {
        imagem = new ImageIcon("darkforest.jpg").getImage();
        timer = new Timer(100, this);
        timer.start();

    }
    // here you define alpha 0f to 1f
    public FadeIn(float alpha) {
        imagem = new ImageIcon("darkforest.jpg").getImage();
        this.alpha = alpha;

    }
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        System.out.println("paint");
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER,
                                                    alpha));
        g2d.drawImage(imagem, 0, 0, null);

    }

    public static void run(JPanel jPanel) {
        jPanel.add(new FadeIn());  
    }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        alpha += 0.05f;
        if (alpha >1) {
            alpha = 1;
            timer.stop();
        }
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Nothing happens, no image is show on the panel. Just to try it out, instead of jPanel.add(new FadeIn()); I have also tried to create a new jFrame and adding a new FadeIn onto that, and it works then. Of course, instead of an image being painted on the jPanel, a new jFrame pops up ontop of the main one, with the image nicely fading in. But that's not what I want happening.

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: *"`imagem = new ImageIcon("darkforest.jpg").getImage();`"* 1) Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL. 2) One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot link to images seen in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556).

Comment: General tip: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Er go:

assuming you have the following sequence of calls:

```
JFrame f=new JFrame();
f.setSize(500, 500);
JPanel j=new JPanel();
f.add(j);
f.setVisible(true);
FadeIn.run(j);
```

you need to change the size as follows:

```
public FadeIn(Dimension d) {
  setSize(d);
  .... // the rest of set up
}
```

then in run:

```
run(Jpanel jPanel) {
  jPanel.add(new FadeIn(jPanel.getSize()));
}
```